# Throwing error from if statement inside try not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, try-catch, throw

I have the below function.

```
private terminateUser = async (req): Promise<any> => {
  try{
    if(req.oper=='cancel'){
      if(!('termStat' in corporate.data)){
       console.log('here');
       throw new ServerError({errorcode:121})
      } else {
        reqbody= this.generateReqbody(req);
       }
    }
   return await Promise.resolve(this.config.message);
  } catch(err) {
    throw new ServerError(errorcode:100);
    }
```

Here , I am getting the console message 'here' inside the if statement !('termStat' in corporate.data)

But it is not throwing the errorcode 121 instead it is throwing the errorcode 100 inside catch. How can I throw the exact errorcode from if statement

Comment: Test against `err` to see if it's a `ServerError` -- if so, regrow with the `error code` from `err`. Note that you have a typo as well: `errocode` vs `errorcode`

Comment: well ... the catch catches the error 121, which is correctly thrown - but the catch ignores the caught error 121 and throws an error 100 - therefore, 100 is the only expected result - by the way, your code would not throw errorcode 100, since your throw is not the right syntax to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
private terminateUser = async (req): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    if (req.oper=='cancel') {
      if (!('termStat' in corporate.data)) {
       console.log('here');
       throw new ServerError({ errocode:121 })
      } else {
        reqbody= this.generateReqbody(req);
      }
    }
    return await Promise.resolve(this.config.message);
  } catch(err) {
    throw err
  }
```

Comment: in other words, no need for try/catch **at all**